Web scraping with Selenium, but I am getting this error: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I have run the same Selenium web ChromeDriver on another code and I did not get an ChromeDriver error, is this a ChromeDriver error? I am also unsure if I am web scraping correctly. I want to scrape under the tab market_open_row if London or New York pops up and if New York pops up I also want to scrape the time it opened. I will provide screen shots and my code.
The screen shot states market_closed_row but it changes as soon as one of the markets open to market_open_row
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

# Use ChromeDriverManager to automatically download and manage ChromeDriver
service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Initialize the Chrome WebDriver with the specified service
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

def find_and_process_time(): # This is the loop beginning to search for London or New York
    # Open the website
    driver.get('https://forex.timezoneconverter.com/?timezone=Africa/Johannesburg&refresh=5')

    # Pause for 5 seconds to allow the website to load
    time.sleep(5)

    # Locate the <div> element with the class "container"
    container_div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "container")

    # Locate the <table> element within the container
    table_element = container_div.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "table")

    # Locate the <body> element within the table
    body_element = table_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body")

    # Locate the <div> element with the class "markets" within the body
    markets_div = body_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "markets")

    # Within the "markets" div, locate all rows with the class "market_open_row"
    rows = markets_div.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "market_open_row")

    # Flag to check if either New York or London is found
    found = False

    # First, check if "London" is in any of the rows
    for row in rows:
        if "London" in row.text:
            print("Found London!")
            found = True
            # Handle London case here if needed
            break

    # If London was not found, check for "New York"
    if not found:
        for row in rows:
            if "New York" in row.text:
                print("Found New York!")
                # Extract the open time from the same row
                time_elements = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "small")
                if time_elements:
                    open_time_str = time_elements[0].text  # Use only the first timestamp found
                    print(f"New York open time: {open_time_str}")

                    # Convert the time string to a datetime object
                    open_time = datetime.strptime(open_time_str, "%I:%M %p")

                    # Calculate the start time, which is 3 hours after the open time
                    start_time = open_time + timedelta(hours=3)
                    print(f"Indicators can only start at: {start_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')}")

                    # Get the current time
                    now = datetime.now()

                    # Check if the current time falls within or after the calculated start time
                    if now >= start_time:
                        print("Conditions met for New York, 3 hours after open time, continuing with the Indicators (CW se beurt)")
                        # No need to sleep or wait, continue to the next steps
                        found = True
                        break
                    else:
                        print("Current time is before the start time of New York, will retry after 5 minutes")
                        break

    # If neither London nor New York was found, or the current time is before the start time, wait 5 minutes and try again
    if not found:
        print("London or New York not found, or New York time is not 3 hours after open time. Retrying in 5 minutes")
        time.sleep(300)
        find_and_process_time()

# Start the loop to find the New York or London time
find_and_process_time()

# Continue with the rest of the script after finding New York or London and the correct time
print("CW se beurt ,Indicators started.")




Expecting to know what this error is, as ChatGTP states it is something with my Chrome Driver but my Chrome Driver works on another Selenium code. Am I on the right path on scraping the elements I want?

It is not necessary to specify a Service with modern selenium. webdriver.Chrome() will suffice
